# I don't have authorized_keys file in my .ssh folder

Tags: linux, ssh, authorized-keys

i installed ssh
apt install open ssh-server
then i type
ssh-keygen -t rsa
the i type Cd .ssh
this directory has the public and private keys but don't have the authorized_keys file. i went to the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and set the path to authorized_keys, then restart ssh, but still the file is not showing.

for this reason it is not enabling other machine to make an ssh connection with my machine using keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can create by file from the remote host by executing `ssh-copy-id username@your-host`.

Alternatively, if you know the public keys, you can manually create the file.

Comment: if i create it,it does not authorize the key and ask for password everytime.